# How to load html with image to label in xamarin.android

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have to load some Html code with Image from website to Label. I custom a label to display Html code and it works well if it doesn't have img but when it has an img it just show a small square. So, I'm looking for on internet and found down a result like i have to implement Html.IImageGetter.
So this code custom label:

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Element.Text))
            Control?.SetText(GetText(), TextView.BufferType.Spannable);
    }


    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

        if (e.PropertyName == Label.TextProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Element.Text))
                Control?.SetText(GetText(), TextView.BufferType.Spannable);

        }
    }

    [Obsolete]
    private ISpanned GetText()
    {
        //renderimg.GetDrawable(Element.Text);
        return (int)Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= 24
            ?Html.FromHtml(Element.Text, FromHtmlOptions.ModeLegacy,new renderimg(), null)
            : Html.FromHtml(Element.Text, new renderimg(), null);
    }
```

and this one for Html.IImageGetter

```
 public Drawable GetDrawable(string source)
    {
        Drawable drawable;
        Bitmap bitMap;
        BitmapFactory.Options bitMapOption;
        try
        {
            bitMapOption = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bitMapOption.InJustDecodeBounds = false;
            bitMapOption.InPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.Argb4444;
            bitMapOption.InPurgeable = true;
            bitMapOption.InInputShareable = true;
            var url = new Java.Net.URL(source);

            bitMap = BitmapFactory.DecodeStream(url.OpenStream(), null, bitMapOption);
            drawable = new BitmapDrawable(bitMap);
            //var url = new Java.Net.URL(source);
            //drawable =  Drawable.CreateFromStream(url.OpenStream(), null);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }

        drawable.SetBounds(0, 0, bitMapOption.OutWidth, bitMapOption.OutHeight);
        return drawable;
    }
```

and it got an error:

> Android.OS.NetworkOnMainThreadException: Exception of type
>   'Android.OS.NetworkOnMainThreadException' was thrown.   at
>   Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallObjectMethod
>   (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo
>   method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00069] in
>   <9ed4c1a7b8844cdcb5330cc881c1cd6a>:0    at
>   Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeAbstractObjectMethod
>   (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self,
>   Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x00014] in
>   <9ed4c1a7b8844cdcb5330cc881c1cd6a>:0    at Java.Net.URL.OpenStream ()
>   [0x0000a] in :0    at
>   NewsApp.Droid.renderimg.GetDrawable (System.String source) [0x00033]

Comment: Could you please share a basic demo so that we can test with it?

Comment: Hi, Jessie Zhang
my sample project here: 
https://github.com/thaihuydang/HtmlImage
Ps: sorry for late response

Comment: I have tested your code , but ti don't have the error as you said. Sorry for late response

Answer (score 0):

I also want to show images inside HTML Label, I have tested your solution and facing the same exception

> Android.OS.NetworkOnMainThreadException on url.OpenStream()

Searching it on Stackoverflow I have seen that it is due to execution on the code in the main thread and you should execute it on another thread or async.

I have your code of GetDrawable working putting it into a Task.Run() and then Wait().

```
public Drawable GetDrawable(string source)
{
    Drawable drawable = null;
    Bitmap bitMap;
    BitmapFactory.Options bitMapOption = null;
    try
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            bitMapOption = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bitMapOption.InJustDecodeBounds = false;
            bitMapOption.InPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.Argb4444;
            bitMapOption.InPurgeable = true;
            bitMapOption.InInputShareable = true;
            var url = new Java.Net.URL(source);

            bitMap = BitmapFactory.DecodeStream(url.OpenStream(), null, bitMapOption);
            drawable = new BitmapDrawable(bitMap);
        }).Wait();
        //var url = new Java.Net.URL(source);
        //drawable =  Drawable.CreateFromStream(url.OpenStream(), null);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.GetBaseException().Message);
        return null;
    }
    drawable.SetBounds(0, 0, bitMapOption.OutWidth, bitMapOption.OutHeight);
    return drawable;
}
```